# Is it possible to have 2 segues attached to the UITableViewCell that point at two different UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Currently I have a `UITableViewCell` and I attached a segue of type `show` there - when user clicks the cell this method gets invoked:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

     if (segue.identifier == "fullEventSegue"){


        fullEventDetails = segue.destinationViewController as? FullEvent


    }
}
```

and then user gets redirected from this cell to the FullEvent class (and view). But now I want to check if that's a user of type A, and if yes then redirect him as usual, but if not - then redirect him to the `PartialEvent`, something like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if (user == "typeA")
    {
     if (segue.identifier == "fullEventSegue"){


        fullEventDetails = segue.destinationViewController as? FullEvent


    }
  }else{

if (segue.identifier == "partialEventSegue"){


        partialEventDetails = segue.destinationViewController as? PartialEvent


    }
  }
}
```

I tried to attach two segues on `storyboard` but when I attach a second one - the first one disappears and for me it looks like I can attach only one segue. Is there any way of fixing it and using both of them at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attach the segues to the view controller instead of the cell.  Then, implement your test logic inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Depending on which user type, call `performSegueWithIdentifier` and pick the matching identifier.